# Is there a way to tell ffmpeg mpdecimate to only evaluate a specific part of the frame?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a 60 FPS screen recording of a significantly slower, variable frame rate, video. It is supposed to, however, be constant frame rate.

Fortunately, frame numbers are present in a fixed area of the screen. Within that area, the only time anything changes is when the frame number changes.

(There are sometimes changes between frames - in *other* parts of the frame - that I would like mpdecimate to ignore. Those changes, however, never appear in the frame count zone.)

Is there a way that I can tell mpdecimate to only evaluate that small 'frame counting' portion of the frame in determining whether sequential frames are duplicates?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show a sample frame?

Comment: Sure. https://ibb.co/VtFFBXK

Edit: I am receiving the video already cropped to that constraint. The number in the lower left is the frame number figure I would like to monitor. My ultimate goal is to have one frame per frame number as shown in that lower left box.

Comment: So the bottom status and control bar is part of the video image?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Will write up a method by tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic method here is to clone the input stream, paint over the undesired portion of the frame with a solid color in one of the copies, run mpdecimate filter, then overlay the untouched copy on top of the de-duplicated copy.

Assume the bottom bar is static except for the frame counter and occupies the bottom 5% of height. drawbox will draw a white box over the top 95% of the frame.

`ffmpeg -i in -vf "split=2[full][masked];[masked]drawbox=w=iw:h=ih*0.95:x=0:y=0:t=fill:c=white,mpdecimate[deduped];[deduped][full]overlay=shortest=1" -vsync vfr -c:a copy out`

Comment: Clever approach. catering to the filter.

Comment: If I know that the final product is supposed to play at a particular frame rate, is there a way to specify that within your command, to avoid having to reencode its output at the desired frame rate? Works brilliantly, by the way!

Comment: Add a `setpts=N/25/TB` after the overlay for a 25 fps playback. I assume you have no audio.

Comment: Correct. Thank you for sharing your expertise.

Comment: "Unable to find a suitable output format for 'setpts=N/24/TB'
setpts=N/24/TB: Invalid argument." I placed it just before -vsync vfr. Was that the wrong spot? Input and output are both .mov files, though I am not beholden to either.

Comment: It's a filter, so right after overlay *inside* the filtergraph

Comment: I wish I knew what that meant, but after having attempted to read the "filtergraphs" syntax section as a non-programmer, I am still not quite sure where I should be putting that and if I have to add characters other than the setpts=N/25/TB to escape the new filter. I tried a variety of different placements and each returned an error of some sort. (I totally understand if you're long since done with my question.)

Comment: The final part of the filtergraph will be `[deduped][full]overlay=shortest=1,setpts=N/25/TB`

Comment: Success! Thank you 